# How to get rid of terminal window when application was launched from command line?

Tags: command-line, 14.04, software-installation

I am running an application which is lying in `/usr/bin/Application/bin/myApp`. To run this file I need to execute `./Application/bin/myApp` in terminal window. Now on running this way a terminal window always remain associated with the application and if I do `Ctrl+c` in that window it closes the application.

Is there any other optimal to run **myApp**, so that I don't see terminal window associated with it. I also tried to run by directly going to `/usr/bin/Application/bin` right click on`myApp` and chose `open with Run Software` but loader appears on it for few seconds and then nothing happens.

I have its `tar.xz` file and I run `tar --strip=1 -xJvf myApp*xz` command to install it.

Answer (score 1):

"nohup" is the way to start a program in a terminal and still keep it running when the terminal quits. To do this, run your command as below:

`nohup ./Application/bin/myApp &`

Then exit the terminal:

`exit`

The process would still be running.
To stop the process, you'll have to open another terminal and find the pid of the process with `pgrep myApp` and kill it.

More details on [this wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

Answer (score 0):

You can start the programm with `./Application/bin/myApp &` to get the application to run in the background.
You can close the terminal without closing the application then.

Comment: ctrl-z will only put the command in bg. But exiting shell will still cause the command to stop.

Comment: If you do not use `nohup` or `disown %%` when you close the terminal the application will receive a SIGINT --- most apps will exit. @Ashish answer is the correct one.